# Change DataGridView ComboBoxCell selecteditem by TextBoxCell value

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I have one `textboxcolumn` and `comboboxcolumn` in `datagridview`. I need to change selecteditem when I enter value in `TextBoxColumn` based on valuemember of `comboboxcolumn`.

> TextBoxColumn- name = itnum 
>   ComboBoxColumn - name = itname

```
ComboBoxColumn
-------------------------
Value           Display
---------      ----------
  1             Item 1
  2             Item 2 
  3             Item 3
-------------------------
```

---

```
Private Sub GV_CellEndEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles GV.CellEndEdit
Select Case GV.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).Name
   Case "itnum"
      GV.Item("itname", e.RowIndex).Value = GV.Item("itnum", e.RowIndex).Value
End Select
```

When I run this code, Error popup like this

[image]

My requirement is when I enter **3** in TextBoxCell, ComboBoxCell should automatically change selectedItem to **Item 3**

Comment: You should do checks prior to setting GV's value if it's from a text box. Make sure that the value entered into "itnum" is a value already within the GV items set, or you'll need to add it to its items. So, If not comboboxcell.items.contains(<enteredvalue>) then items.add(<enteredvalue>), then select it.

Comment: If that doesn't work, make sure you're selecting a value that's a string. I.e. GV.Item("itnum",e.rowindex).value.tostring()